# Download videos using IDM

Tags: internet, download-manager

Hii i am using internet download manager 6.11 version. When i try to download videos download starts from 0% even the video fully buffered. How to make the IDM download directly 100% once background video buffered fully??

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstanding of how IDM works.

What it does it capture the download link as the page or page elements are loading. It can then download those links instead of the broswer.

If what you are trying to do is get the videos that have already been downloaded by your browser, you have use a program like [VideoCacheViewer](http://videocacheview.en.softonic.com/).

Comment: @KarmegarajaM, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

IDM downloads videos directly from server (like a normal file download), and it has absolutely no relation with browser video cache. Better you download videos soon after the download video button appears. This will save your bandwidth.

Additionally, there is an addon **[CacheViewer Continued](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer-continued/)** for Firefox, and you may refer to this mozilla forum **[Once a video has fully buffered,like from youtube etc. is there any way i can save it without any extra s/w or add-on?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/922243)**